# Dagger2 dependency issue in AndroidStudio 3.0

Tags: android, dependency-injection, build.gradle, dagger-2, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to add Dagger2 dependency in AndroidStudio 3.0. But due to this reason I am unable to add dagger2 dependency.

***Could not find method apt() for arguments [com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. Open File***

```
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8"
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10"
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just Add these dependencies. Remove apt

```
// Dagger Dependencies (Dependency Injection)
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.12'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `apt` dependency for android. Remove it. You also want to use the same version for the `annotationProcessor` and the dependency. It's `2.13` right now.